# Pegar somente o valor repetido de um Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de pegar somente os nomes que se repetirem em um array de input do tipo text.

> Por exemplo: ['Daniel','Sarah','Maria','Daniel','Felipe']

Retornasse o 'Daniel'.

> Segue o Código da montagem do array e logo em seguida gostaria de
>   pegar os repetidos.

JS:

```
var mensagem = "";
var camposInput = new Array();

$("input[name='options2[]']").each(function () {      
    camposInput.push($(this).val());
});

console.log("Lista:", camposInput); // Retorna os nomes
console.log("Repetido:",?????); //Retonar o nome Repetido
```

Comment: Não é duplicata, eu não quero remover os valores repetidos, eu que trabalhar com os valores repetidos

Comment: Danielle, a resposta duplicada não remove os valores repetidos, ela adiciona numa array os valores repetidos sem alterar a array original.

Comment: @Sam Verdade, Ja conseguir atraves da resposta. Obrigada